# C : Image Segmentation

Tags: algorithm, c, image

My primary coding language is C++, but I occasionally use C. I wrote some simple image segmentation using Union-Find algorithm. Feel free to comment anything!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

static size_t const MERGE_CRITERION = 50;

typedef struct Segment Segment;

struct Segment {
    unsigned char value;
    size_t parent;
    double average;
    size_t size;
};

size_t FindCompress(size_t N, Segment pixels[static N], size_t i) {
    if (i >= N) return SIZE_MAX;
    if (pixels[i].parent != i) {
        pixels[i].parent = FindCompress(N, pixels, pixels[i].parent);
    }
    return pixels[i].parent;
}

bool Union(size_t N, Segment pixels[static N], size_t i, size_t j) {
    if (i >= N || j >= N) return false;
    size_t root_i = FindCompress(N, pixels, i);
    size_t root_j = FindCompress(N, pixels, j);
    if (root_i == root_j) return false;
    if (fabs(pixels[root_i].average - pixels[root_j].average) > MERGE_CRITERION) {
        return false;
    }
    if (pixels[root_i].size < pixels[root_j].size) {
        size_t temp = root_i;
        root_i = root_j;
        root_j = temp;
    }
    pixels[root_j].parent = root_i;
    double new_average = ((pixels[root_i].average * pixels[root_i].size)
            + (pixels[root_j].average * pixels[root_j].size)) / (double)(pixels[root_i].size + pixels[root_j].size);
    pixels[root_i].average = new_average;
    pixels[root_i].size += pixels[root_j].size;
    return true;
}

int main() {
    FILE* img = fopen("sample.bmp", "rb");
    FILE* outimg = fopen("sample_gray.bmp", "wb");

    unsigned char header[54] = {0};
    fread(header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, img);
    fwrite(header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, outimg);

    uint32_t width = *(uint32_t*)&header[18];
    uint32_t height = *(uint32_t*)&header[22];
    uint32_t stride = (width * 3 + 3u) & ~(3u);
    uint32_t padding = stride - width * 3;

    printf("width %u, height %u, stride %u, padding %u\n", width, height, stride, padding);

    size_t image_size = width * height;
    Segment greyscaled[image_size];

    unsigned char pixel[3] = {0};
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            fread(pixel, 3, 1, img);
            unsigned char gray = (unsigned char)(pixel[0] * 0.3 + pixel[1] * 0.58 + pixel[2] * 0.11);
            greyscaled[i * width + j] = (Segment){.value = gray, .parent = (i * width + j),
                                                  .average = gray, .size = 1};
        }
        fread(pixel, padding, 1, img);
    }
    size_t change_count = 1;

    size_t iteration = 0;
    while (change_count > 0) {
        change_count = 0;
        for (uint32_t j = 1; j < width; j++) {
            if (Union(image_size, greyscaled, j, j - 1)) {
                change_count++;
            }
        }
        for (uint32_t i = 1; i < height; i++) {
            if (Union(image_size, greyscaled, i * width, (i - 1) * width)) {
                change_count++;
            }
            for (uint32_t j = 1; j < width; j++) {
                if (Union(image_size, greyscaled, i * width + j, (i - 1) * width + j)) {
                    change_count++;
                }
                if (Union(image_size, greyscaled, i * width + j, i * width + j - 1)) {
                    change_count++;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Iteration %zu, change_count %zu\n", ++iteration, change_count);
    }

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            size_t root = FindCompress(image_size, greyscaled, i * width + j);
            unsigned char gray = (unsigned char) greyscaled[root].average;
            memset(pixel, gray, sizeof(pixel));
            fwrite(&pixel, 3, 1, outimg);
        }
        fwrite(pixel, padding, 1, outimg);
    }

    fclose(img);
    fclose(outimg);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Original example image:

[image: Original example image]

Using `MERGE_CRITERION = 10`:

[image: Merge criterion 10]

Using `MERGE_CRITERION = 20`:

[image: Merge criterion 20]

Answer (score 3):

As the Standard Library headers are independent of each other, it makes sense to include them in consistent order - alphabetical is a good choice.

The `main()` function here is very long - more than a screenful.  That's usually a sign that it should be split into functions for the different responsibilities.  In particular, the file reading seems worthy of its own reusable function.

We need to be much more robust when reading files.  If either `fopen()` fails, we very soon use the returned null pointer, causing Undefined Behaviour.  If `fread()` or `fwrite()` fail, then the program continues regardless, likely producing meaningless results.

It's unwise to assume that the file format's endianness agrees with the host endianness like this:

> ```
>  uint32_t width = *(uint32_t*)&header[18];
>  uint32_t height = *(uint32_t*)&header[22];
> ```

It's better to compose values explicitly from the byte stream.

Answer (score 2):

### Use const

In `FindCompress` and `Union` the parameters `N`, `i` and `j` could be passed as const as they are not changed in the functions.

### Avoid using keywords as function names.

In C `union` is a keyword, even though the function name is currently in CamelCase I would still recommend against it.

### Styling

- Segment struct definition

```c
typedef struct Segment Segment;

struct Segment {
    unsigned char value;
    size_t parent;
    double average;
    size_t size;
};
```

Can be written as:

```c
typedef struct {
    unsigned char value;
    size_t parent;
    double average;
    size_t size;
} Segment;
```

- CamelCase for functions and variables is uncommon in C usually snake_case is preferred, however this is of course an opinionated item.
- Use brackets on `if...else` statements even if they are one line. There's a chance more lines will be added to the if...else statement later on. Forgetting to add brackets when this happens can lead to bugs that could have been avoided if brackets where added from the start.
- Make use of empty lines for readability. Before return statements and around `for/while/if...else` statements are good places for this.

Example with these points applied to the `FindCompress` function:

```c
size_t find_compress(const size_t n, Segment pixels[static n], const size_t i) {
    if (i >= n) { return SIZE_MAX; }

    if (pixels[i].parent != i) {
        pixels[i].parent = find_compress(n, pixels, pixels[i].parent);
    }

    return pixels[i].parent;
}
```